# Unable to reference a view in another database from XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpinc

I have a repeat where the value loops through documents in the current database, these documents contain a database and view name. The repeat then opens the database and view and retrieves data from within them:

```
var dbOther:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(null, doc.getItemValueString("Database"));
if(dbOther != null){
    var lookupView:NotesView = dbOther.getView(doc.getItemValueString("ViewName"));
    var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = lookupView.createViewNavFromCategory(key);
}
```

This works fine on all browsers but if I view the xpage in the Notes Client I get the following error: Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.getView(string) null

I have tested that the dbOther variable is set by writing the Server and FilePath properties to a log. I checked that it could see the views by generating a loop using getViews and getAliases, again all view aliases were written to the log without an issue.

I have manually entered the view name in case the value was not being selected from the document correctly but received the same error.

Is there a way I can connect to a view in another database in XPiNC? I have found an XSnippet which allows you to dynamically add view data sources to your page, I think this may get around my problem but wanted to find out if there was an alternative solution before I re-write everything!

Comment: Long time back I read about this issue here: http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=B21BE03574FE36AD852578CB0066B5AD. Basically the author used the syntax of `@Name("[CN]",@Subset(@DbName(),1))+"!!dbname.nsf"` to call the database. May be this works for you.

Comment: I wrote that post originally.  That was a problem.  I'm told it was fixed in later versions but I've not really verified that.  I don't do much with XPiNC any more.

Comment: I did find this solution prior to posting this, but I wasn't sure how to set it as a NotesDatabase object. It did retrieve the database but I then wasn't sure how to use getView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some of these other ways of getting a handle on a database:

This one uses `""` instead of the `null` parameter to indicate current server:

```
var dbOther:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("", doc.getItemValueString("Database"))
```

This one uses `database.getServer()` instead of the null parameter:

```
var dbOther:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), doc.getItemValueString("Database"))
```

This one uses `sessionAsSigner` to get access to the database (instead of using the credentials of the current user):

```
var dbOther:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(), doc.getItemValueString("Database"))
```

---

Are you using a Lotus Notes 8.5.3 client?

Comment: Hi, I tried each solution you suggested, the one that fixed the problem was to use database.getServer(). Thanks for all your help

Comment: The reason database.getServer() is the solution is based on the question "What is the current server?". 'null' and '""' are used for the current server. Within a browser the current server is the server running your application. But within XPiNC the current server is your local machine, because the local XULRunner is the server that provides your XPages. If you don't have a local replica of your database you must tell Notes which server to use.