# XPages cannot access database

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, access-control, xpages-ssjs

I have 2 database, one containing XPages (Mobile Web App, let's call this database A) and another one containing the documents (database b). In my test unit, everything works fine. When I access the mobile web app, it access data from database B flawlessly. But when I install them in the client's server, the web app cannot access database b. I checked all ACL entries and I think it's fine. The error on the page in:

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=161, col=18: 'ecrDB' is null
   at [/sjs_common.jss].getCRViewDetails()
```

The script that causes the error is:

```
function getCRViewDetails(){
 158:   
 159:   var ecrDB:NotesDatabase = ECR().mainDB;
 160:   var viewDetails:Array = new Array();
 161:   if(ecrDB.isOpen()){   //----- HERE IS THE ERROR LINE!
 162:       //var vw:NotesView = ecrDB.getView("Drafts");
 163:       var vw:NotesView = ecrDB.getView(mainConstants.VIEW_MAIN);
 164:       var docs:NotesDocumentCollection = vw.getAllDocumentsByKey(session.getEffectiveUserName(), true)    
 165:       //var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument();
 166:       var doc:NotesDocument = docs.getFirstDocument();
 167:       while(doc != null){
 168:           viewDetails.push([
 169:               doc.getItemValueString("ProjectTitle"),
 170:               doc.getItemValueString("CRNumber"),
 171:               doc.getUniversalID()
 172:           ]);
 173:           //print(doc.getItemValueString("ProjectTitle") + ">>" + doc.getItemValueString("CRNumber"));
 174:           //doc = vw.getNextDocument(doc);
 175:           doc = docs.getNextDocument(doc);
 176:       }   
 177:   }
```

This is how I access database b (ECRDB):

```
function ECR(){
  34:   
  35:   //private properties and methods ---------------------------------
  36:   
  37:   //Setup document
  38:   var SetupDoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("(Setup)","");
  39:   
  40:   // try to connect to Main DB if the sessionScope.ECRMainDBPath has been set
  41:   if(sessionScope.containsKey("ECRMainDBPath") && sessionScope.containsKey("ECRDataRepPath")){
  42:       try{
  43:           var ECRDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(
  44:               SetupDoc.getItemValueString("ECRMainServer"),
  45:               sessionScope.get("ECRMainDBPath"),
  46:               false);
  47:           var DataRep:DataRepository = new DataRepository(
  48:                   session.getDatabase(SetupDoc.getItemValueString("ECRMainServer"),
  49:                   sessionScope.get("ECRDataRepPath"),
  50:                   false));
  51:           
  52:           var ecrSettingsDoc:NotesDocument = ECRDB.getProfileDocument("eCRSettings","");
  53:       }catch(e){
  54:           print(e.message);
  55:           print("Error: Cannot access eCR Main. Please check if Anonymous is at least Reader Access");
  56:           ECRDB = null;
  57:       }
  58:   }else{
  59:       //TODO put this in init()
  60:       if(!(view.getPageName().equals("/login.xsp") || view.getPageName().equals("/selectDivision.xsp"))){
  61:           context.redirectToPage("selectDivision.xsp");
  62:       }
  63:   }
  64:   
  65:   return {
  66:       test : "Hello Orga!",
  67:       
  68:       setupDoc : SetupDoc, //get Setup Document
  69:       
  70:       getSetupValue : function(fieldName){
  71:           return this.setupDoc.getItemValueString(fieldName);
  72:       },
  73:       
  74:       //get ECR Main database (content database)
  75:       mainDB : ECRDB, 
  76:       
  77:       //get eCRSettings doc from the Main DB
  78:       mainSettings : ecrSettingsDoc, 
  79:       
  80:       //get full database path (with server)
  81:       getFullDBPath : function(){
  82:           return this.mainDB.getServer() + "!!" + this.mainDB.getFilePath();
  83:       },
  84:       
  85:       //get Data Repositoy Object
  86:       getDataRep : function(){ return DataRep; },
  87:       
  88:       //get Data Repository  //TODO remove this
  89:       //dataRep : DataRep.getDatabase(),
  90:       
  91:       //get URL for Data Repository
  92:       //getDataRepURLPath : DataRep.getURLPath,
  93:       
  94:       getDBURL : function(){
  95:           return context.getUrl().toString().split(view.getPageName())[0];
  96:       },
  97:       
  98:       getSplittedOrder : function(){
  99:           return this.mainSettings.getItemValueString("SplittedOrder");
 100:       }
 101:   };
 102: }// end of ECR declaration
```

I have no other idea what is the possible problem with the databases. Can you tell me what are the factors that I need to check in order to successfully access database b? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Accessing another DB from XPage can be a bit finicky. You may have to use `sessionAsSigner.getDatabase` or change some settings on server to get handle of the database. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863496/unable-to-reference-a-view-in-another-database-from-xpinc), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030470/how-to-use-dblookups-in-different-database), [this](http://quintessens.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/xpages-unable-to-open-database-on-other-server/) and [this](http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=B21BE03574FE36AD852578CB0066B5AD).

Comment: Does the settings document definitely exist on the client db copy?

Answer (score 0):

Your ECRDB variable will initialize only if this statement is true:

```
sessionScope.containsKey("ECRMainDBPath") && sessionScope.containsKey("ECRDataRepPath")
```

Doublecheck your sessionScope variables prior to call ECR() function.